# More space between the ordinate axis ans plot labels

Tags: legending, plotting, labeled

I have this graphics.
All I want is more place like a space or interval between labels and the ordinate azis. How could I do that?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{E^(-k t) , E^(-k t) (-1 + E^(k t)) + 0.1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  PlotLabels -> {Style["u[t]", 16], Style["x(t)", 16]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["t", Bold, 16], Style["x(t),u(t)", Bold, 16]}, 
  TicksStyle -> {{FontSize -> 16}, {FontSize -> 16}}], {k, 0, 2}]
```

Thanks!
[image: la]

Comment: Try `Style["x(t),u(t)\n", Bold, 16]`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, it's only a simple workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Notice how much simpler the code can be if you were use the `BaseStyle` option to set the font size. Also, notice that the code below does not show the spacing problem you are experience. I am running V11.3.0 on MacOS 10.13.4 (High Sierra).

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{E^(-k t), E^(-k t) (-1 + E^(k t)) + 0.1}, {t, 0, 10},
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16},
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
    PlotLabels -> {"u[t]", "x(t)"},
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "x(t), u(t)"}],
  {k, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Sadly, this is how it looks like on windows: https://imgur.com/GrWenvn.png .
+1 for BaseStyle, that thing is pretty usefull.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your label inside `Pane` and specify `FrameMargins` for it.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {E^(-k t), E^(-k t) (-1 + E^(k t)) + 0.1}, {t, 0, 10}
  , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
  , PlotLabels -> {Style["u[t]", 16], Style["x(t)", 16]}
  , AxesLabel -> {Style["t", Bold, 16], 
    Pane[Style["x(t),u(t)", Bold, 16], 
     FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}]}
  , TicksStyle -> {{FontSize -> 16}, {FontSize -> 16}}
  ]
 , {k, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image]